# Pusher not working on Phonegap for Android

Tags: android, cordova, pusher

I'm facing a problem and would really appreciate your help...

> Android SDK: 4.0
>   Phonegap: 1.8.1
>   Pusher: 1.12

I have created an Android project using Phonegap that needs to receive server notifications through Pusher.

I'm running it in Eclipse and AVD emulator, but the problem is that every time I try to establish a connection to pusher, I get an `Unavailable` state from the bind to `state_change`.

I have tested the connection to Internet in the emulator browser and it works fine. I have also tested that the server is responding and that the Pusher key is the right one by testing my code on Firefox.

This are the steps I have followed:

1. I have included the `WebSocket.java` and `WebSocketFactory.java` files in the src folder.
2. I have included `websocket.js` file in my js folder and included a reference in the `index.html` file.
3. I have included a reference to http://js.pusher.com/1.12/pusher.js in the index file.
4. I have included the following line in my Android `App.java` file:  this.appView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebSocketFactory(this), "WebSocketFactory");
5. This is the code I'm using to connect to Pusher:

```
// Connect

var pusher = new Pusher(CONFIG.PUSHER.APP_KEY);
pusher.connection.bind('state_change', connectionStateChange);

function connectionStateChange(state) {
    alert(state.current);
}
```

Is there something I'm missing? Any ideas on why the connection is not working or about where to check?

Thanks for your help.

Chadid

Answer (score 0):

For version 2.x of pusher-js and above the library will work within PhoneGap without any additional requirements or setup. Simply include the library and use it - no need for `WebSocket.java` or `WebSocketFactory.java`.

---

For version 1.x this blog post and associated code demonstrates how to get Pusher working on PhoneGap:
http://blog.pusher.com/2012/7/5/pusher-on-phonegap-for-android